# Strange bug when typing import copy in iPython-QtConsole (Anaconda)

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I wonder if anyone has experienced this weird behavior: Every time I type:

```
import copy
```

In the iPython qtconsole, it freezes (Not Responding). I have to kill the window and launch it again. The only way It can work is if I copy-paste 'import copy' with other pieces of code as one block in the copy-paste.

I appreciate any insight

Python 2.7.7-1, Anaconda 2.1, iPython 2.3.1

**Update:**

It appears that it's about the import command only, I was trying to import seaborn import sns and same happened.

Comment: @asmeurer Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the qtconsole and all its dependencies by running `conda install ipython-qtconsole` in a cmd shell.

Comment: @asmeurer Yes, It's updated. I use Anaconda. I have version 2.3.1 at the moment. So I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Right, but this will also update the dependencies of the qtconsole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem got solved with the recent iPython-qtconsole update to 2.4.1 version, automatically done by Anaconda.